# Python: Masking ERA5 data (NetCDF) from shapefile (polygon/multipolygon)

Tags: python, polygon, netcdf, shapefile, masking

I want to select grid cells from ERA5 gridded data (surface level only) that are inside geographical masks for North- and South-Switzerland (plus the radar buffer), to calculate regional means.
The 4 masks ([masks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge51i.png)) are given as polygons/multipolygons ([polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAGjZ.png)) in a shapefile and so far for 2 of the masks I was able to use salem roi to get what I want:

```
radar_north = salem.read_shapefile('radar_north140.shp')
file_radar_north = file.salem.roi(shape=radar_north)
file_radar_north.cape.mean(dim='time').salem.quick_map()
```

However, for the radar_south and alpensuedseite shapefiles the code didn´t work at the beginning (wrong selection or shows no data), and now the nothing works anymore (?). I don´t know why, as I have not changed anything from the first time to the second.

If someone sees the issue or knows a different way to mask the ERA data (which is maybe quicker) I would be grateful! (I was unsuccessfull with the answers from similar questions here).

Best
Lena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work if you are working on netcdf files

```
import geopandas as gpd
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray
from shapely.geometry import mapping

# load shapefile with geopandas
radar_north = gpd.read_file('radar_north140.shp')

# load ERA5 netcdf with xarray
era = xr.open_dataset('ERA5.nc')

# add projection system to nc
era = era.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)

# mask ERA5 data with shapefile
era_radar_north = era.rio.clip(radar_north.geometry.apply(mapping), radar_north.crs)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, it worked!! I tried it this way too, but it didn´t work because I didn´t know that I had to add a projection system to the nc data. So thanks again!